# Вывод категорий с подкатегориями

Tags: php, yii2

Как мне вывести на одной странице все родительские категории со ссылками на их дочерние категории, структура примерно  такая:

На одной странице идут все родительские категории;
При клике на категорию, на новой странице отображаются ее вложенные категории.

CategoryController:

```
public function actionIndex(){
    return $this->render('index', [
        'model' => $this->outTree($id)
    ]);
}

public function getAllArray(){
    $all = Category::find()->all();
    $array = array();
    foreach($all as $v){
        $array[$v->parentId][] = $v;
    }
    return $array;
}

public function outTree($parentId) {
    $array = $this->getAllArray();
    if(isset($array[$parentId])){
        echo '<div>';
        foreach($array[$parentId] as $v){
            echo '<div>'.$v->name.'</div>';
            echo '<div>'.$v->id.'</div>';
            echo '<div>'.$v->parentId.'</div>';
            $this->outTree($v->id);
        }
        echo '</div>';
    }
} 

protected function findModel($alias)
{
    if (($model = Category::findOne(['alias' => $alias, 'active' => 1])) !== null) {
        return $model;
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
```

Связь родительских категорий с дочерними:

```
public function getParent()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Category::className(), ['id' => 'parentId']);
}
```

Как мне сделать такой вывод во view, сейчас вывод идет в контроллере? На данный момент на одной странице выводятся все родительские категории и под ними их дочерние. Нужно ли что-то прописывать в UrlManager?

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо передовать в get параметре в контроллер ид родительской категории,
в контроллере получать массив дочерних и передовать его(массив) во въюху, там отображать.
Если параметр пустой то выводим верхний уровень меню.

```
public function actionIndex(){
    $parentId = Yii::$app->request->get('pcat');
    return $this->render('index', [
        'model' => $this->outTree($parentId)
    ]);
}
```

Соответственно ссылки генерить с параметром pcat

Comment: не совсем понял, можете тут описать это все? я вставил ваш код, но у меня выводится тоже самое

Answer (score 0):

CategoryController: изменить

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $parentId = Yii::$app->request->get('pcat');
    return $this->render('index', [
        'categories' => $this->getCategories($parentId)
    ]);
}

public function getCategories($parentId)
{
    if ($parentId) { // если есть родительская категория
        $all = Category::find()->andWhere(['parentId' => $parentId])->all();
    } else { // если это верхний уровень
        // точно не знаю как у вас в базе, предполагаю что у кат. верхнего уровня parentId = NULL
        $all = Category::find()->andWhere(['parentId' => null])->all();
    }
    return $all;
}
```

Въюха category/index.php:

```
<?php
foreach($categories as $category) { ?>
   <div><?= Html::a($category->name, ['/category', 'pcat' => $category->id])?></div>
   <div><?= $category->id ?></div>
   <div><?= $category->parentId ?> </div>
<?php } ?>
```